# cannot drag and drop calender extender and other ajax controller in content page

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Before i added a script manager in my masterpage to display a slideshow image,ajax controller works fine in my content page.Now i cannot drag and drop ajax controller to my content child page even i have removed the script manager.

and i have register ajax reference in content page

> Blockquote

```
 ##<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor" tagprefix="asp" %>    ##
```

http://helpme.come

Please guide me the correct way to achieve my objective.

Comment: try adding the Ajaxcontrol toolkit reference to page

Comment: already added..still got error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Tool -> Import Export Setting -> Reset All Settings -> All Settings (This Option is in Visual Studio 2012 Only) -> Finish.

2010 it Will Be -> No, just Reset settings, override my current settings -> General Development Setting -> Finish
```

Reference `Ajax Dll` again it will work.

Comment: it works!! now i can drag and drop the calender extender to the text box..but when i run it and click on the text box,nothing comes out.